# Every counter with a fullstop at the end

Tags: numbering, punctuation

Is there an easier way than redefining all commands to have every counter followed by a fullstop?

Chapter counter, theorem counter, figure counter etc. should always look like

> 1.3.4.

and not like the default

> 1.3.4

---

I use the following amsthm-theoremstyle:

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
```

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: If you use one of the KOMA-Script document classes, more than half the job will be done with the `numbers=enddot` class option.

Comment: I use scrarcl. So `numbers=enddot` did a good job but still a few counters don't end with a dot e.g. theorem counters etc.

Comment: What package do you use to define your theorem-like structures?

Comment: I use the `amsthm` package.

Comment: But then the counter for theorems will receive also a full stop (see my answer). If this is not the case, please add to your question a minimal version of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using one of the KOMA_Script document classes, the `numbers=enddot` class option will use a full stop for the counters for sectional units, figures, tables. If you load the `amsthm` package, counters for theorem-like structure will also have a full stop:

```
\documentclass[numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\begin{theo}
test
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are using a custom theorem style, use the sixth mandatory argument of `\newtheoremstyle` to add the necessary punctuation:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{.}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
```

To satisfy the requirement mentioned in a comment for the end dot position when the optional argument is used, some additional work will have to be done using the last mandatory argument for `\newtheoremstyle`:

```
\documentclass[numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2.}\thmnote{ \normalfont(#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheoremstyle{breaknodot}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{\thmname{#1}\thmnote{ \normalfont(#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{breaknodot}
\newtheorem*{theo*}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\begin{theo}[label]
test
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}
test
\end{theo}
\begin{theo*}
test
\end{theo*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me. Then I think it depends on the theoremstyle. See above for the style I use.

Comment: @Meinzlein: see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for you're update. Now I'm quite there. The only thing is now, that Theorems without a number (`begin{theo*}`) will have an enddot as well, I only want them to have an enddot if theres a counter.

Comment: I don't know how you defined the theo* environment. Anyway, for unnumbered theorems, you can add a new style: `\newtheoremstyle{breaknodot}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{breaknodot}
\newtheorem*{theor}{Theorem}`

Comment: But then I would need to change the style for every single Theorem depending on wether it's numbered or not. I just defined theo as `\newtheorem*{\theo*}{Theorem}`.

Comment: You can say `\theoremstyle{break}` and then use as many `\newtheorem` commands you like to build your numbered theorems and then `\theoremstyle{breaknodot}` and `\newtheorem` for the unnumbered theorems, so it's only adding one more line. Or am I misunderstanding your last comment?

Comment: Oh, yes. That's true. I encountered another problem. "Theorem 1.2.3 (label).". But the dot should be at the following positioin: "Theorem 1.2.3. (label)".

Comment: @Meinzlein let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1959/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-meinzlein)

Comment: Just a note for completeness sake: as the conclusion of the chat discussion shows, the last version of the code solves the problem.